# dataTransfer.files array is empty in chrome when drop event raised from a div

Tags: vuejs2, drag-and-drop, vue-component

i created 'BaseDropzone' component in nuxt 2 for uploading files. when i try to upload file by dragging file and dropping in dropzone sometimes files array in dataTransfer is empty. it only happens in Chrome. firefox works fine. i use ubuntu 20.04 lts.

here is my 'BaseDropzone' component:

```
<template>
  <div
    @drop.prevent="onDrop"
    @dragenter.prevent
    @dragover.prevent
    @dragleave.prevent
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  emits: ['dropped'],
  methods: {
    onDrop($event) {
      //  Chrome Error: sometimes in chrome array of files is empty
      //  Firefox works fine
      if ($event.dataTransfer.files.length === 0) {
        console.error('drop file again');
        return;
      }
      this.$emit('dropped', [...$event.dataTransfer.files]);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```